# Replacing Defined Characters

Tags: excel, vba, replace

Attempting to write a Sub to replace defined characters in a cell. I've defined all the characters in an array named SC.

I am looping through each populated cell in Column 1, and I want it to look at them one at a time, and if it finds anything in that cell that matches what's in my array SC, I want it to replace that character with a blank. I get a type 13 mismatch when I run this, on line "Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), SC, "")".

```
Sub SpecialCharactersRemoval()
Dim SC As Variant
Dim lr As Long

lr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = 1 To lr
SC = Array("~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", ":", ";", "<", ">", "?", "|", "{", "}", "[", "]", ",", "+", "_")
Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), SC, "")
Next i
End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this code to do what I want? Thank you.

Comment: Loop through each element of the array, replace can't handle looking at an entire array in one go.

Comment: Can you show me what they code would look like? I assume you're saying there should be a nested loop in my main loop?

Comment: You do not need to loop the cells only the array.  You can reference the entire range: `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Replace SC(i), ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you define `SC` loop through it so replace is using each element instead of the entire array.

```
Sub SpecialCharactersRemoval()
Dim SC As Variant
Dim lr As Long
Dim ele As Variant
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet 'You can change this to whatever sheet you want to do this on
    lr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 
    
    For i = 1 To lr
        SC = Array("~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", ":", ";", "<", ">", "?", "|", "{", "}", "[", "]", ",", "+", "_")
        For Each ele In SC
            .Cells(i, 1) = Replace(.Cells(i, 1), ele, "")
        Next ele
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

You may want to change `lr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` to `lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` It will give more consistent results.

If the cells with `@` are hyperlinks of any kind removing the `@` will not remove the hyperlink.

If you don't want to loop through the cells as well (As per Scott Craner's comment), you will need to tweak a couple things. `"*"` will need to be `"~*"` same goes for `"?"` to `"~?"` as they are wildcards and will delete other stuff in this situation.

```
Sub SpecialCharactersRemoval()
Dim SC As Variant
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet
    SC = Array("~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "~*", "(", ")", ":", ";", "<", ">", "~?", "|", "{", "}", "[", "]", ",", "+", "_")
    For i = 0 To UBound(SC)
        .Range("A:A").Replace SC(i), ""
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```